# Problems with fetching data from a database

Tags: php, database, mysqli

My Current Code:

```
<?php
                if(require("connect.php"))
                {
                $result = $mysqli->query('SELECT title, description, portfolio FROM Portfolio;');
                while($o = $result->fetch_object()) 
                {
                $title=htmlspecialchars($o->title);
                $description=htmlspecialchars($o->description);
                $portfolio=htmlspecialchars($o->portfolio);

                echo <<<ARTBOX
                <div class="artbox">
                <div class="photocontainer">
                    <img src="$portfolio" alt="$title" />
                </div>
                <div class="artboxtitle">
                    $title
                </div>
                <div class="artboxdescription">
                    $description
                </div>
                <div class="artboxenquiry">
                    <img src="images/enquiry.png" alt="Make an Enquiry" href="#" />
                </div>
            </div>
ARTBOX;
}
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "An error occurred, please try again.";
                }
?>
```

Returns the error: "Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_object() on a non-object in ..."

Can someone tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: Your query is probably failing, causing `mysqli_query` to return `false`. Thus your `$result` is `false` and you can't call `fetch_object()` on `false`.

Comment: check your query if you there is any mispelling of names

Comment: Check `if($result)` before calling member functions.

Comment: just realised that the table had a capital at the start as in "Portfolio" instead of "portfolio", simple yet I couldn't pick it up.

Comment: you should use a convention for naming your tables. for example you have a table and field with the exact same name and casing, that can lead to a lot of confusion. maybe use table names in plural

Comment: How can I accepts this as an answer since you just commented on it?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the return value of [mysqli::query()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php). It can return `FALSE` in case of an error. So `$result` will be `FALSE` and `FALSE->fetch_object()` doesn't make sense - and it does call a member function on a non-object.

For debugging, you can output error messages:

```
$result = $mysqli->query('SELECT title, description, portfolio FROM Portfolio;');
if (!$result) {
  die($mysqli->error);
}
```